# stop refreshing js file in django templates

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have created countdown timer with Django templates which showed on HTML templates when the page refreshed data on an HTML page is an update but it also reset countdown timer. I don't want that is there any way to stop refreshing script or update data without refreshing.

app.js

```
var count = 8
var counter = setInterval(timer , 1000)

function timer(){
    count = count-1
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        clearInterval(counter);

        return window.location.href = urlFromDjango
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= count + " secs";
}
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<script>
    var urlFromDjango = "{% url 'app:result' %}"
</script>

<body>
     <h1 id="timer"></h1>
</body>

<h1>{{user.username}}</h1><br>
<h2>score -{{user.userextend.score}}</h2>
<form action="{% url 'app:detail' quiz_id=que.quiz.id question_id=que.id %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% for choice in que.answer_set.all %}
         <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
         <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.answer }}</label><br>
     {% endfor %}
     <button><a href="{% url 'app:detail' %}">Next</a></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store that information somewhere, so even if you refresh the count information is not lost. A simple solution would be to store it someplace like either cookies or local storage. Here is an example:

```
var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count-" + window.location.pathname)) || 8
var counter = setInterval(timer , 1000)

function timer(){
    count = count-1
    localStorage.setItem("count-" + window.location.pathname, count)
    if (count <= 0){  
        clearInterval(counter);
        return window.location.href = urlFromDjango
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= count + " secs"
}
```

Comment: Updated ! But its still not storing remaining time

Comment: Umm, can you check your local storage in the browser to see if there is anything stored in there? Also, can you please see if there is any error in console?

Comment: After updating above code , its not showing any timer it directly redirecting to the result page

Comment: My bad.I forgot that using localStorage, it will return string instead of int. You need to explicitly typecast it to integer. I have updated the answer.